# Unable to stop memory leak in useEffect hook ,React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a landing page in React with below function for changing image in carousel.

After I navigate away, it gives error `'Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.'`

Below function change carousel image in every 2 second.

```
  // state to find idex
  const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = React.useState(0); 

  //array of images to display
  const images =  [
  image1,image3,image2,
    ];
    
  //function that changes image index in every 2 second
  const nextImage = () => {
    setImageIndex((prev) => (prev + 1) % images.length);
    setTimeout(nextImage, 2000);
  };

  // function to initiate above function, the memory leak happens here
  React.useEffect(nextImage, []);
```

I have gone through some StackOverflow questions and changed my timing function as below but the error still exists,

```
// useEffect triggers this functions

const nextImage = () => {
    let unmounted = false;
    if (!unmounted) {
      setImageIndex((prev) => (prev + 1) % images.length);
      setTimeout(nextImage, 2000);
    }

    return () => {
      unmounted = true;
    };
  };
```

Question I referred https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038029/10515390 have answer but I did not get the clear  idea.

Comment: If you do setTimeout you also need to do clearTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i've created a simple snippet for you. Hope you'll understand this. And since you are using `setTimeout` make sure you've also used `clearTimeout`. And re run the effect when the image index changes.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Test() {
    const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = React.useState(0); 

    const images =  [ 'image1','image2','image3'];
  
    useEffect(() => {
      let timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setImageIndex((imageIndex+1) %images.length);
      }, 2000);
      
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId)
      }
    }, [imageIndex])

    return <h2>{images[imageIndex]}</h2>
  
}




ReactDOM.render(
  <Test/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```