# Memory leak when performing update on unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component using the [react-polling](https://github.com/vivek12345/react-polling) library to poll an endpoint. It will keep on polling till the expected response is obtained. During polling, it shows a message that polling is in progress. After polling terminates, it will show a success response.

A quick overview of the key props of the Polling component:

- **onSuccess** - callback that takes the axios response and returns *true* to continue polling and *false* to stop polling
- **onFailure** - callback called when the API/endpoint call wasn't successful.
- **render** - Renders content

The entire implementation is present in [ReactPolling.js](https://github.com/vivek12345/react-polling/blob/master/src/ReactPolling.js). Please take a quick look/skim if required (especially the [render method](https://github.com/vivek12345/react-polling/blob/master/src/ReactPolling.js#L185-L192)).

### Code organization

I have a main `App` which renders `Page1Component`. It uses the `Polling` component
which uses the above `ReactPolling` library. I have a prop named `renderOnSuccess` of type `() => JSX.Element | void`. It is a function which I call after the polling is successful. It could return

1. A `JSX.Element` which is the content to be shown after the polling is completed successfully. This will be set as a state variable and will be rendered.
2. Return nothing - in this case, nothing will be shown after polling is successful.

**Case 1 (Render success message content on same page/component):** (Works fine)

I return a content from the `renderOnSuccess` method and it will be shown after polling is completed.

[Codesandbox code for polling success case 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/polling-success-uf5mn).

Output would be:

```
Page 1
Hello I am polling

..after polling completes..

Page 1
Success
```

Note that the `Success` message is shown from the same page/component (`Page1Component`)

**Case 2 (Render new page after polling)** (Problematic)

In this case, I want to change the top-level component itself. So, I change to page 2 from page 1.

For this, I maintain a state variable to track the page to be rendered and change it from the `renderOnSuccess` callback in `App.js`.

[Codesandbox code for polling success case 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/polling-warning-wzmp5).

Output in this case is

```
Page 1
Hello I am polling

..after polling completes..

Page 2
Page 2 content
```

In this case, I get a warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

After reading posts on SO for the above warning ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038008/how-to-stop-memory-leak-in-useeffect-hook-react)), I have added a `useRef` to check if the component is still mounted or not before setting `contentToBeRendered` in the Polling component and now the warning goes away.

[Codesandbox code for polling warning fix](https://codesandbox.io/s/polling-warning-fix-qxj18)

Code for fix in Polling component:

```
const unmounted = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    unmounted.current = true;
  };
}, []);

//In onSuccess
let content = props.renderOnSuccess() || null;
if (!unmounted.current) {
  setContentToBeRendered(content);
}
```

---

**Question:**

Is this the right way to handle the warning?

The fixes recommending to use `useRef` usually involve making an async call. Thus, the component could be unloaded before the call returns. But here, the call to `renderOnSuccess` **would never return** as the parent component rendered some other page (The `setContentToBeRendered` will never happen).

I'm doubtful if this is the right fix and is there still a memory leak because the call to `renderOnSuccess` never returns in **case 2**.

Comment: have you tried using the Cancellation Axios feature?

Comment: @R.M.Reza The issue is not when making API calls. It is after we get a successful response for the polling to stop - we call the caller passed callback to render something on the page. But in case 2, the caller decided to change the top-level page/component which led to the React warning.